# Does posix_fadvice call the broken API sys_fadvice64 or the fixed sys_fadvice64_64?

Tags: api, linux-kernel

I'm wanting to experiment with the fadvice functions and reading up
discovered that there is a `sys_fadvice64` function which is obsoleted by `sys_fadvice64_64`

But, the new function has the same parameters.  Why didn't they just fix the old one?

And secondly, does `posix_fadvice` call the broken API or the fixed one? how can I tell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new function uses `loff_t` for `len`, whereas the old one uses `size_t`.  To maintain binary compatibility with programs compiled against the old function, a new function was required.

`posix_fadvise()` should call the new function, if it is available.  You can test this by compiling a test program that uses `posix_fadvise()`, and using the `strace` utility to see which system call it uses (don't forget to compile with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`).